# requires api 11, min is api 9 but runs on api 9

Tags: android

i'm playing around with code analyze in Android Studio.

i've got the following class:

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject> {

    public void addAll (Collection<? extends MyObject> collection){ 
        super.addAll(collection);
    }

    public void addAll (MyObject... items){
        super.addAll(items);
    }
}
```

both of those methods are getting flagged with the following problem:

"Call requires API level 11 (current min is 9)"

This is not new code.  Its been around since the start of the project.  It runs on Android API 9 (whatever that was)

Why is this a problem?  More importantly, why doesn't it cause some kind of run time error on a device running API 9.

Comment: because that methods are added in api11 revision

Answer (score 1):

The Flag is there to tell you that the function it will not work below API 11 [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20T%3E))

You can still make it run on the device with API 11 or higher though.

If you really need to run it on API lower than 11 I suggest you check the API version like this

```
int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentApiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    // do some method for HoneyComb(API 11) or higher 
} else{
    // do some method for something lower than HoneyComb(API 11)
}
```

Or else change the minSdkVersion to state that the application is for API 11 and higher in your project `build.gradle` file

```
defaultConfig {
        ....
        minSdkVersion 11 // Minimum version that you want
        targetSdkVersion 22
        ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your project `build.gradle` and change

```
defaultConfig {
       .....
        minSdkVersion 9  // change 9  to 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```